# Dillema with newing an item in WPF MVVM

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I have built a form that displays the properties of items contained in an observable collection. This observable collection is in a ViewModel to which the datacontext of the View is bound to.

When the New button on the form gets clicked, a new Item gets added to the observable collection, and with the help of the collectionview is set to the current item. The same form is used. This time, because of the new item, the fields are empty.

Now, I want there to be only one new item in the observable collection. Because of this, I need to somehow distinguish between an Item and a New Item.

So, before the New requirement I had the following Observable Collection in my ViewModel:

`public ObservableCollection<ItemViewModel> ItemTypes { get; private set; }`

But now I need to be able to distinguish between a New Item and an old item. I've been trying to do a couple of things like building a base class, of which I derive Item and New Item, but this seems really wastfull since I can't think of anything to put in the derived classes, they are really only there to help to see if there's one Empty Item in the observable.

What can I do?

**Edit**

```
private void CreateNewItemType()
{
   if (DoesNewItemTypeAlreadyExist())
   {
      return;
   }

   Model.ItemType itemType = new Model.ItemType();

   ItemTypeViewModel itemTypeViewModel = new ItemTypeViewModel(itemType)
   {
     IsNew = true
   };

   ItemTypes.Add(itemTypeViewModel);
   itemTypesCollectionView.MoveCurrentTo(itemTypeViewModel);
}

private bool DoesNewItemTypeAlreadyExist()
{
    return ItemTypes.Any(a => a.IsNew == true);
}
```

Comment: bool IsNew on the model and then bind differently?

Comment: Yes, that thought has crossed my mind as well. --  but what do you mean with bind differently? Basically, my code just goes through the observable collection to see if there's an empty type. With your suggestion I have thrown everything over to have a IsNew variable, but planned still to do a seach through the observable collection to find a true...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a bool property on your item (IsDirty for example).  When new, IsDirty is False.  The first time something is changed, set it to true.  Then you can have a check on the command property for your Add button that creates the new item, to check and see if there are any `IsDirty = False` items in the collection.  If so, then set that item to selected.  If not, then add a new item and select it.

In the past what I have done to do change detection is create a dictionary of String, String. The dictionary contains the name of the property and the original value.  In the Changing event handler for the property in my model class, I add an add or remove call that checks to see if an item for that property is there, if so, check current value with changing value.  Call `OnPropertyChanged("IsDirty")` as appropriate.

Is dirty checks to see if there are any items in the dictionary.  The beauty is that if you change the values back to their original values, the record will regain it's IsDirty=False status.

## Example of implementation

```
Private Sub OnAddress1Changing(ByVal value As String)
    If Not m_dirtyFields.ContainsKey("Address1") Then
        AddDirtyField("Address1", Address1)
    Else
        If m_dirtyFields("Address1") = value Then RemoveDirtyField("Address1")
    End If
End Sub

    Public m_dirtyFields As New Dictionary(Of String, String)

    Private Sub AddDirtyField(ByVal ColName As String, ByVal OrigValue As String)
        If Not m_dirtyFields.ContainsKey(ColName) Then
            m_dirtyFields.Add(ColName, OrigValue)
            OnPropertyChanged("IsDirty")
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub RemoveDirtyField(ByVal ColName As String)
        If m_dirtyFields.ContainsKey(ColName) Then
            m_dirtyFields.Remove(ColName)
        End If
        OnPropertyChanged("IsDirty")
    End Sub

 Public ReadOnly Property IsDirty() As Boolean
        Get
            If m_dirtyFields.Count > 0 Then 'There are items so record is dirty
                Return True
            Else
                Return False
            End If
        End Get
    End Property
```

Comment: This is real good. I guess I was doing to much thinking there, with all the derived empty items and what not. Before you answered, I had a comment that suggested something along the same lines as you have: to simply have a boolean value suggest if a certain viewmodel is new or not. Based on his comment I already was plowing my code to implent it and to see how it works. For step 1. I will add the bool property, leave it at the default when filling them with items from the DB. When adding a new item I will set the bool to true - or the other way 'round, like you suggest with IsDirty ;-)

Comment: Sounds like a plan and a half.  Let me know if there is anything else.

Comment: I plan to edit my post and post the small bit of code that it is now. Then I'll see and modify code some more to implement what you posted.